# Docusign connect - What is the expected lag time between envelope sign completion and Docusign triggering Https Post Request

Tags: docusignapi

Docusign Connect allows to send Envelope notifications through HTTPS POST request. I wanted to know, how much lag can there be from the time the user has completed signing till the time Docusign triggers the HTTPS POST REQUEST. Is there a time limit within which Docusign triggers this HTTPS POST request, after the user has completed signing ?

Answer (score 0):

In the developer's environment (demo) it may take a bit longer than in production. It shouldn't be more than 1-2 minutes though. In production you should expect to see it within 10-20 seconds.
That also depends on the volume and how busy the servers are, so it's not always going to be the same.
Note that the "last mile" is the potential latency of your own server receiving the request, but usually that doesn't add even a second to the time, but it could if your server is located in somewhere with low bandwidth.